# finalWords is not defined, how do I avoid this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import time

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        words = []
        finalWords = []

    def getWords(self,url):
        sourceCode = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(sourceCode, 'html.parser')
        words = soup.get_text().lower().split()
        [finalWords.append(item) for item in words if item not in finalWords]
        print(finalWords)

game = Game()

game.getWords("http://members.optusnet.com.au/charles57/Creative/Techniques/random_words.htm")
```

when I call game.getWords I get an error that says finalWords is not defined, how do I avoid this? I'm new to using classes. Thanks.

Comment: finalWords is no longer in scope from your __init__ function when you are running the getWords. You may also want to look at the list extend() and filter() methods rather than using a list comprehension to append missing items.

Comment: From site, `"Last updated 3rd June 1997"`. So [early 2000s](http://members.optusnet.com.au/charles57/Creative/)

Answer (score 1):

You define `finalWords` in `__init__` but then `__init__` ends, and that local variable disappears. You probably want to store it as an attribute of the instance, by using `self.finalWords` throughout.

BTW, your use of a list comprehension in `getWords` creates a list of `None` which you then throw away. Don't use a list comprehension for its side effects. You should use a regular `for` loop instead, or a `set` if order isn't important (since a `set` can contain a particular item only once).

Answer (score 1):

Your `finalWords` is a local variable in your constructor, not an instance field.

Unlike in Java or C#, you have to *always* qualify your instance fields with the actual instance, which in methods is normally named `self`.

This will work:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.words = []
    self.finalWords = []

def getWords(self, url):
    # your code....
    self.finalWords.append(...)
    print self.finalWords
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `words` and `finalWords` instance attributes. Like this:

```
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import time


class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.words = []
        self.finalWords = []

    def getWords(self,url):
        sourceCode = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(sourceCode, 'html.parser')
        self.words = soup.get_text().lower().split()
        [self.finalWords.append(item) for item in self.words if item not in self.finalWords]
        print(self.finalWords)

game = Game()

game.getWords("http://members.optusnet.com.au/charles57/Creative/Techniques/random_words.htm")
```

Comment: s/class/instance/ please. Otherwise your answer is correct.

Comment: @9000 Could you explain, what you mean by s/class/instance/ ?

Comment: This syntax is a "substitute text" syntax used by [vi](http://www.linfo.org/vi/search.html), sed, awk, etc. I'm trying to say that `self.words` is an instance attribute, it belongs to an instance of class `Game` and _not_ the class itself. You have different values of `.words` in different instances. Class attributes are defined under `class`, usually it's various constants. Technically, methods are class attributes, too.